# create a panel for login using MVC /account/login

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using MVC4/5's auto generated code there is a shared `_LoginPartial.cshtml` that allows me to call a small (Login) box in any cshtml view like so `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")`   This is a pretty cool and responsive element that will change depending on if a user is logged or not and show their UserName.

My goal is to have a drop down panel, I was wondering if I could put jquery in the mix and on click it show the page.

Here's the code I tried.

```
$(function () {
    $('#loginBtn').on('click', function () {
        var path = '/Account/Login'
        $("#loginContent").load(path);
    });
});
                            </script>

                            <button id="loginBtn">Login</button>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="loginContent"></li>
```

This passes in the view but it doesn't show inside a floating panel. Here it's just pushing the page down.

Is there a c#/razor equivalent I can place in my `_LoginPartial.cshtml` or `_Layout` page to keep the `Html.Partial` call while rendering the partial view in a small panel.

Comment: Maybe you could render the Login Partial within `#loginContent` from page load and just keep it hidden? Then on `$('#loginBtn').click()` you could show `$(#loginContent)`